# How to display an image via an async base64 string in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I use the http client from Angular to load a base64 string from the backend. As soon as the string is received, the image should be displayed in the view. I tried the code below, but Angular responded because the string cannot be loaded into the view due to XSS security policies.

```
public image$: ReplaySubject<string>  = new ReplaySubject(1);

public loadImage(): void {
  ...
  this.deviceService.getItem(deviceId, itemId).then((response) => {
    this.image$.next(response.imageString);
  }
}
```

```
<img [src]="(image$ | async)" />
```

So I tried to use the DomSanitizer to trust the string. If the string is static, this works fine, but I wasn't able to set it up properly for the async case.

```
public image: string = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl("data:image/png;base64,...");
```

```
<img [src]="image" />
```

I tried a lot of things also via DOM or ViewChild, but I could not find a solution for my use case. How can I display an image from a base64 string that I get via an async call?

Comment: I did just run into the same problem. In my case I generate the base64 code within Electron through executing a process though

Comment: In my case I return a Promise object though `<img [src]="getBase64() | async">`

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest you several options:

### Use custom pipe to transform your string to SafeResourceUrl

**safe.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
```

**html**

```
<img [src]="image$ | async | safe" />
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/7FgIYx8TmVmxQsNVRfLj)**

### Convert string to SafeResourceUrl manually

**ts**

```
image$: ReplaySubject<SafeResourceUrl> = new ReplaySubject(1);
...
this.image$.next(this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(response.imageString));
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/cN0Vi5uzL2dMiEaNGXkI?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Thank you so much! That is really helpful. I adjusted it slightly to match how I use it. Do you have any idea what I might oversee here with Promises? https://ng-run.com/edit/oDkavT9nF8FEtqKJFaoN?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I call now `[src]=loadImage | async | safe"

Comment: You shouldn't do that because you return a new Promise on each change detection cycle that causes a new change detection cycle

Comment: So I should cache it with members and accessing them from there directly?

Comment: Right https://ng-run.com/edit/WA08mNShwubuBmp77ADF?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I will add your bounty in 22h (once i am allowed to). Thanks so much!

Comment: sir in my case image src attribute showing object-object